# GROUP BY in a TIME type field - MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

In MySQL I have a table, one of the fields is of type TIME (field HORA):

[image]

By giving a select like this:

```
SELECT hora FROM tabela GROUP BY hora
```

Nothing is returned, if I GROUP BY in any other field, it works. Does this behavior make any sense? If so, how to group the same results?

Comment: Does it work if you use `SELECT * FROM TABELA GROUP BY HORA`?

Comment: Which tool do you use to run your query?

Comment: @NasirRiley no....

Comment: @forpas PHP (PDO)

Comment: Then the problem is with your php code. Your query would not return any rows only if the table is empty.

Comment: Please add more details to make this a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - table schema, example data ([not an image of example data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)), and your expected result. You can share a live example via https://www.db-fiddle.com/.

Comment: add the column type for the Hora column,

Answer (score 0):

time sort works

```
declare @tmp as table(id int, name varchar(20), hora time)

insert into @tmp
(id,name, hora)
values
(1,'andre','07:00:00'),
(2,'caio','06:00:00'),
(3,'carlos','07:00:00'),
(4,'andre','09:00:00')

select * from @tmp
order by hora desc
```

output:

```
  id    name    hora
  4 andre   09:00:00.0000000
  3 carlos  07:00:00.0000000
  1 andre   07:00:00.0000000
  2 caio    06:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: check what culture your sql server is set too. us-en works

Answer (score -1):

```
Select *
from hora
group by hora
order by hora ASC;
```

```
group by 
  datepart(year, start_date),
  datepart(month, start_date), -- omit if grouping by year
  datepart(week, start_date), -- omit if grouping by month
  datepart(day, start_date), -- omit if grouping by week
  datepart(hour, start_date), -- omit if grouping by day
  datepart(minute, start_date); -- omit if grouping by hour
```

This should Return all rows in the hora column. If there is still a discrepancy there could be an issue with how the table is column is formatted.

https://popsql.com/learn-sql/sql-server/how-to-group-by-time-in-sql-server

Comment: Its not working... if i group by NOME, it works fine.

Comment: how is the column formatted?. Is it for time date or int.